# Calling a class function from a static function through this pointer

Tags: c++

Is it possible to call a class function via `this` when passed as an argument to a static function?

This is how the function is called within the class Foo

```
Foo::Bar(this, NULL);
```

This is how I would like to call it by passing `this` in an argument structure:

```
void Foo::someFunction()
{
    BarArgs barArgs;
    barArgs.context = this;
    ...
    Retry(barArgs);
}

static void Retry(LPVOID args)
{
    BarArgs *pstBarArgs = (BarArgs *)args;
    (pstBarArgs->context)->Bar(pstBarArgs->context, NULL);
}
```

Comment: _`Retry(barArgs);`_ pass the address: `Retry(&barArgs);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refer to `args` as a pointer to `BarArgs` in `Retry` you have to pass the address of the variable like this when you call it:  `Retry(&barArgs);`

Then it should work OK.